# Deleting certificate and private key (just added from a .p12 file) from the keychain

Tags: ios, macos, security, terminal, keychain

I'm building a script that:

1. import to the keychain a p12 file;
2. build and sign a specific Xcode project;
3. delete the imported certificate.

I'm importing the certificate for code signing with this `security` command:

```
security import privateKey.p12 -t agg -k MyCustomKeychain.keychain -P password -A
```

Then I'm building and archiving the app via `xcodebuild`.

And now I don't know how to delete both certificate and private key from the command line.

**EDIT**

I solved it by creating every time a new keychain, and then deleting it.